# I am looking for a code through which I can check whether the E-Mail account is existing or not

Tags: email-validation, email-verification

I am looking for a code through which I can check whether the E-Mail account is existing or not.

Comment: this question doesn't really meet muster for this site, if need help implementing one of those solutions... maybe that could go on serverfault or something, but you haven't asked a real question at this point... if you have a programming problem with some existing library, that could fit here... in short "what have you tried?"

Comment: I changed my question. Well, the programs which are available online to check whether the Email account is existing or not are not at all working. I am unable to figure out the solution.. I developed a product in VC++, which can extract email ids from websites now i want to add another module for verifying the email account existence.

Comment: Even if anyone is having a solution in any other programming language apart from VC++ then please post it as i am ready to understand the logic and implement it through VC++.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a code through which I can check whether the E-Mail account is existing or not.

You are trying to solve an impossible task. There can't be a reliable way to know if particular e-mail address points to a valid account or not.

First of all "account exists" is not a well-defined term.

A few examples:

- There is a service called https://www.mailinator.com/ It provides a service that you can send an e-mail to any address anything@mailinator.com and it will receive it and you can check it from their Web-UI. I've just generated new GUID and I'm pretty sure that nobody in the whole history of the world before this moment has ever sent an e-mail to SomeUniqueGuidString-80372aed-0928-4899-8efb-3d617416174b@mailinator.com. Still, that account existed for years and it is mine now (as well as yours).
- Assume that while your application is being run in New-York, aliens come to the Earth and just destroyed the Southern hemisphere with some fancy weapons. Obviously accounts of Argentinian goverment don't exist at this point anymore (assuming they host them in the Argentina). But you can't know about it in New-York.
- Assume I have my personal domain with two personal emails odd@example.com and even@example.com. I configure my e-mail server to drop every e-mail that goes to odd@ on odd days of month and similarly for the even@. Does even@ account exists on January 1 (odd day)?

Probably companies that provide similar services just accumulated over years huge bases of e-mail addresses that they know existed at some point, for example because e-mails were successfully delivered there or there even were responses. Still no such database can be guranteed to avoid errors (both false positives and false negatives)